# Bad Plan after a couple of days

Tags: sql-server-2008, execution-plan

I have this query that runs fine for a couple of days (from the application) and then slows down to where it can't even finish.

If I rebuild the plan, it flies.

There is a signifigant amount of data being modified in the tables that it is using.

Also if I run it from SSMS and turn ARITHABORT on, it works fine. If I turn ARITHABORT off, it hangs and hangs.

Side note - Stats are repopulated every Monday. Today (Thursday) the plan is bad. The table in question has 1.4 billion records with 9 million changed since Monday.

Is there a way I can increase performance so I don't have to rebuild this plan?

Bad Plan
[image: Bad Plan]

Good Plan
[image: Good Plan]

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled parameters for each plan?  My guess is they're probably different.  If so, you could use OPTIMIZE FOR (good parameter)

Comment: I have. They are the same.

Comment: Cant you rebuild stats more often? I excpect its your stats that are causing this.